# Firefox isn't getting .each() or all elements

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have a bit of code:

```
$('.audio_player embed').each(function() {
   $(this).attr('wmode','transparent').wrap('<div></div>');
   console.log($(this));
});
```

What this code does is finds all embed within divs with a class of .audio_player and then for each of them it will change the wmode to transparent and wrap it in a div.

This code is working perfectly in Chrome and all of the embeds are getting the wmode changed. However in Firefox, its only getting the first  instead of all of them.

I added the console.log to see if they are getting picked up. And in Chrome, its picking up multiple embeds but not in Firefox.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This should work. Do you mind setting up a test case on [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that replicates this problem?

Comment: You should only need to do `$('.audio_player embed').attr('wmode','transparent').wrap('<div></div>');`.  A sample of (non-)working code would be useful.

Comment: I just did some more testing and it does work - but there is a problem. What I'm going on the page is loading in more articles into the same page. It finds all the <embed>s that were already on the page, but fails to find new ones added to the page. Its a bit strange because it works find in Chrome :S

Comment: @lonesomeday - that is how I had the code originally, I just added the each to see if it made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its my fault - it's not browser specific. I noticed that when I load a second page - it doesn't find the embed, so it doesn't add the wmode. But when I load a third page, the embed on the second page works and their page doesn't. I will investigate this further. I think a delay before the function might be in order.

Comment: That was definitely the issue, for some reason in Firefox, the function executes before the added elements are added to the DOM. In all other browsers it's added to the DOM first. I just created a function for a one second delay:

 function funcDelay(){
  setTimeout(setFlash, 1000);
 }

Answer (score 0):

try this, it is a little more verbatim and using each, made few small modifications:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("div.audio_player").each(function() {
        $("embed", this).attr("wmode","transparent").wrap("<div />");
    });
});
```

added ready

Comment: also make sure you have <!DOCTYPE HTML> since embed is HTML5, not sure if that will make huge difference